# Are there any known deficits of "relevant logic"?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, proof

The principle of explosion is the law of classical logic and similar systems of logic, according to which any statement can be proven from a contradiction. Some early formal systems like Frege's [Begriffsschrift](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-logic/) contained hidden contradictions in the basic axioms, but the fundamental problem doesn't vanish even if the basic axioms are free from contradictions (=consistent). The problem is that it's all too easy for a human to make a mistake leading to a contradiction.

One strategy how this problem is addressed in everyday live is to be suspicious with respect to chains of reasoning which wander too far off from the topic at hand. This strategy could be called the relevance principle.

This problem also motivated the development of different systems of *paraconsistent logic*. It seems to me that *relevance logic* is one of these systems, even so I admit that its main goal is to avoid the paradoxes of material and strict implication. From the texts I read about relevance logic, I conclude that it's quite successful at formalizing the relevance principle (via the *variable sharing principle*). However, what I miss so far are investigations whether there are important and relevant theorems that can't be proved if the relevance principle is adopted.

What makes me uncomfortable about the relevance principle is that complex numbers can be used to prove some statements about natural numbers which can be very difficult to prove without them. So I wonder whether there exist good justifications for the relevance principle. However, this is also a more direct question about the existing systems of relevance logic and their *propositional variable sharing principle*. Their proof theory seems to be designed with the goal that implications violating the *variable sharing principle* can't be proved, without compromising the ability to prove implications satisfying the *variable sharing principle*.

However, I didn't find any indications whether these goal were achieved. Will I find such indications (or even proofs) if I read more thorough expositions of relevance logic, or is there something wrong with my expectations that such indications (or proofs) should be given?

Comment: Relevance logic (RL) tries to avoid the [paradoxes of material/strict implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication) - also, it tries to exclude inferences like `The moon is made of green cheese. Therefore, either it is raining in Ecuador now or it is not.` which are classically valid, but are ordinarily counterintuitive. In this sense they are 'closer' to "everyday uses of logic reasoning". Instead, you seem to assume that RL is a "strategy" to avoid "long and complicated chains of reasoning" (?)… Why would you think that? Could it be that you misunderstood RL?

Comment: The use of quotation marks here vexes me greatly.

Comment: @stoicfury I rewrote the question without quotation marks. I also tried to make more definite statements. For the remaining vague statements, I added short explanations how the vagueness arose.

Comment: @DBK Of course it is possible that I misunderstood RL. However, I think it is more likely that i didn't succeed in writing a clear question, especially in explaining what I mean by the *relevance principle*. I clarified in the question now that *relevance logic* is quite successful at formalizing the relevance principle, at least in my opinion. But my question is whether the relevance principle itself can be justified (for example as a special case of Occam's razor).

Comment: The *relevance principle* states informally that for any implication `P->Q`, `P` and `Q` must share at least one **propositional variable**. Hence the relevance principle is better known as the *variable sharing principle*. The **relevance** here concerns the 'topical continuity' of `P` and `Q`. It has nothing to do with selecting (?) which `Ps` and `Qs` are relevant or important, if that is what you mean. Hence I don't understand how this might affect the provability of "important and relevant theorems" (like, say, intuitionistic logic, which, rejecting LEM, makes certain proofs impossible)…

Comment: @DBK An investigation whether the *variable sharing principle* affects the provability of "important and relevant theorems" is exactly what I'm looking for. However, in order to better capture the essence of the relevance principle, the *variable sharing principle* must be accompanied by modifications of the proof theory (similar to linear logic) to avoid irrelevant propositional variables creeping in. But these modifications make it less obvious that all "important and relevant theorems" can still be proved.

Comment: OK, now I understand what you mean. Your point is that the semantics of *relevant implication* (P implies Q) have a peculiar proof-thereotical notion of *relevant entailment* (P is a proof of Q). You would like to know what happens if we were to apply this to math, in the same way that intuitionistic logic yields constructive mathematics: **Which kind of theorems would still be provable in "relevant mathematics"?** This is a tough one, because I don't know of any applications of RL to math, RL is mainly used in the domain of philosophical logic.

Comment: I would suggest that you rephrase your question under the title *Which kind of theorems would still be provable in "relevant mathematics"?* and add these remarks as well as the analogy to intuitionistic logic/math and, possibly, by deleting the reference to "Occam's razor" and "complicated chains of reasoning", which seem to me misleading more than being helpful. BTW that would make a great question and I would revise my downvote and upvote :) (There might be some ground to argue that your question really belongs to Math.SE, but I don't think so.)

Comment: @DBK I tried to incorporate your suggestions while still keeping in mind what actually motivated me to ask this question. It might actually not be the great question you hoped for, because I only ask about the *propositional relevance logic* (because that's what   I read so far). However, asking which kinds of theorems would still be provable only becomes interesting for 1st-order predicate logic, but *1st-order predicate relevance logic* is only introduced in more thorough expositions of relevance logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if  problems you are wondering about exists.

Maybe (A-> B) -> ((A -> (A->B)) , (Converse Contraction) is one of them  if you think it should be valid that is. (it isn't valid in E and R)

Do you find (A-> B) -> ((B -> A) -> (A -> B)) paradoxical?

The lenght of a proof depends on which axioms and rules you use Hilbert style syatems are always longer than Gentzen style systems. to which system are you refering?

I think the problems are more in the field of:

Which relevant logic do you mean in the first place? E, T, R , Ack  or even another one?
I was just reading that even in E there are some paradoxes.
(Entailment volume 1 par 14.6 aptly named "paradox regained)

What is negation in the first place? (my current score is that there are 12 different versions) 
Is the disjunctive syllogism valid ? (Q, P v ~Q => P)

Problems with the Conjunction (there is a difference between ((P&Q) -> R) and (P -> (Q -> R)) don't ask me what.

Comment: Thanks, both "(A->B)->((A->(A->B))" and "(A-> B) -> ((B -> A) -> (A -> B))" satisfy the variable sharing principle, so these are definitively the type of problems I was asking about. So all I have to do now is convince myself that they are really not valid in E and R, and then try to understand whether this is actually intended or not. I knew that there exist many different versions of relevant logic like E, T, R, or ..., but I didn't fully understand why.

Comment: "(A-> B) -> ((B -> A) -> (A -> B))"  Is valid   "(A->B)->((A->(A->B))" is invalid

Comment: I'm not so sure that Gentzen style systems always have shorter derivations than Hilbert style derivations.  In any Hilbert system with a rule X(x, y), x|-y, condensed detachment is a derivable rule of inference making the (CCCqprCpr, CqCpr) into a complete derivation.  I'm not entirely clear what you mean by a Gentzen style proof (I'd guess proof trees... or do you mean any natural deduction style proof?), but is the Gentzen style proof really that short?

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer to [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8202/does-the-finitary-proof-of-the-consistency-of-relevant-pa-shows-that-first-order/8203#8203), relevant logic+PA, although successfully proving its own consistency by finatary means, something not possible in first order logic+PA, it fails to show that there are integers that are not quadratic residues. This is a fairly standard piece of number theory to lose, if we are interested in only conservative extensions of PA; however it could be taken to mean a very different kind of arithmetic is possible under relevant logic.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with relevance logic is that it is not monotonic

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonicity_of_entailment about monotonic

in Relevance Logic

P-> Q does not imply P-> (R -> Q)

I am not even sure it is valid if R is an theorem of Relevance logic

Comment: Stated like this, it's not necessarily a problem. What I like to know is whether facts like this can turn out to be problems, for example by increasing the length of some proofs by more than a small constant factor, or by not being able to prove some implications satisfying the *variable sharing principle*.